# drawing circle in flex

Tags: actionscript-3, flexbuilder, geometry

I'm using flex sdk and trying to draw primitive geometry figures, what is wrong in following code? i tried without the trigger(placing) of button, but did not work.

```
 <mx:Script>
     import flash.display.Sprite;
     import flash.display.Shape;

     private function draw_circle():void
     {
         var myCircle:Shape = new Shape();
         myCircle.graphics.beginFill(0x00000, 1);
         myCircle.graphics.drawCircle(0, 0, 30);


         addChild(myCircle);
     }


 </mx:Script>

  <mx:Button x="30" y="0" name="circle" click= '{draw_circle()}'>



 </mx:Button>
```

Comment: What's wrong with the code? It doesn't work. (Tell us what you mean by "did not work", and we'll be more able to tell you how to fix it.)

Comment: when i invoke drawcirle() method from button, circle was not rendered. So i tried with creationComplete(), it also failed.

Comment: When i tried the same actionscript code under File->new actionscript project, its working fine!! how do i get it working in a flex project??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `endFill` after you `beginFill`:

```
private function draw_circle():void
{
    var myCircle:Shape = new Shape();
    myCircle.graphics.beginFill(0x00000, 1);
    myCircle.graphics.drawCircle(0, 0, 30);
    myCircle.graphics.endFill();
    addChild(myCircle);
}
```

Appropriate documentations could be found [here](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/Graphics.html#beginFill%28%29).

> The fill is not rendered until the
>   endFill() method is called.

Answer (score 0):

```
private function draw_circle(event:Event):void
{
   var myCircle:Shape = new Shape();
   myCircle.graphics.beginFill(0x00000, 1);
   myCircle.graphics.drawCircle(0, 0, 30);
   myCircle.graphics.endFill();


   addChild(myCircle);
}
```

also...

```
<mx:Button x="30" y="0" name="circle" click= 'draw_circle(event);'>
```

If you don't specify endFill(), you're likely to run into important memory problems but the circle should still be drawn though

Comment: That's not what the docs are saying. No `endFill` call - no fill.

Comment: my mistake, i thought it would render (similarly to lineStyle) but create a memory leak... by the way , i didn't omit endCircle intentionally in my example, I certainly wouldn't like to suggest that it's not needed!